# In Pandas, how can I combine column-wise DataFram to a row-wise DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

**I have two DataFrames. One is column-wise, which has observations added by column. The second adds observations row-wise:**

```
    foo     2024-01-01  2024-02-01
--  -----   ---------   ---------
0   4010    100.00      10.00
1   4020    101.00      11.00
2   4030    102.00      12.00
3   4040    101.00      11.00

    Date        Total
--   ----        -----
0   2024-01-01  35.86
1   2024-02-01  3.91
```

**I want to combine these two reports on the `Date` index/value, like this:**

```
    foo     2024-01-01  2024-02-01
--  ----    ---------   ---------
0   4010    100.00      10.00
1   4020    101.00      11.00
2   4030    102.00      12.00
3   4040    101.00      11.00
4   2200     35.86       3.91   <<<
```

Here is the toy data I'm working with:

```
date1 = date(2024, 1, 1)
date2 = date(2024, 2, 1)

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
        "foo": ["4010", "4020", "4030", "4040"],
        date1: [100.00, 101.00, 102.00, 101.00],
        date2: [10.00, 11.00, 12.00, 11.00],})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
        "Date": [date1, date2],
        "Total": [35.86, 3.91]})
```

Comment: What should the value of `foo` be? You write `2200` in the example but where did this come from?

Comment: @stelioslogothetis, good catch. All data in the second table `df_2` is `foo == 2200`, and I didn't notice the inconsistency when I freestyled the results example. Total and 2200 are the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

date1 = date(2024, 1, 1)
date2 = date(2024, 2, 1)

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
        "foo": ["4010", "4020", "4030", "4040"],
        date1: [100.00, 101.00, 102.00, 101.00],
        date2: [10.00, 11.00, 12.00, 11.00]})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
        "Date": [date1, date2],
        "Total": [35.86, 3.91]})

# Transpose df_1 and set the index as 'foo'
df_1_transposed = df_1.set_index('foo').T

# Add a new row with the values from df_2
df_1_transposed['2200'] = df_2.set_index('Date')['Total']

# Transpose back to original shape
result = df_1_transposed.T.reset_index()

print(result)
```

[image]

Comment: I toyed with the example and `df_1_transposed['2200'] = df_2.set_index('Date')['Total']` is doing a lot of work to match on date column. I was trying something like `merge(on='Date')` and getting nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to transpose the first df

```
df_1_transposed = df_1.T.reset_index()
```

then

```
df_1_transposed.columns = df_1_transposed.iloc[0]
df_1_transposed = df_1_transposed.iloc[1:]
```

then you can concat them

```
combined_df = pd.concat([df_2, df_1_transposed], axis=1)
```

Comment: I was working with `concat()` and it gives me problems with alignment with the date values.

Comment: thats why i thought of transposing the data set first